# Should I create two authetication Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing a rails application which has basically two users. One is a typical user that posts questions and other is an expert that answers these questions (Answers can only be given by expert). An expert can only be created by approval of the developer/admin while anyone can sign_up to be a typical user.

I found various ways to approach this problem in Rails. What is the best approach to such a problem?

- Should I create two separate authentication(devise) models?
- Should I give any of the two separate roles(cancan) to a single user model.

Comment: According to me you should follow second approach. Should i give any of the two seperate roles(cancan) to a single user model.

Comment: and why do you say that?